# How to install postgresql_wordpress local on a win or linux machine?

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, cloud

I am trying this out:
https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku

Its simply a wordpress which you can install on heroku, BUT before you deploy it there you have to install plugins because on heroku itself you only have reading rights. Therefore I want to test several plugins locally and then upload them...

But xampp doesn`t work with postgresql....

What are some alternatives running localy wordpress with postgresql?

Comment: Well, no alternative is needed. Just install Postgresql (locally) and you can test locally. Download is here: http://www.postgresql.org/download/

Comment: WordPress is not designed to work on PostgreSQL anyway. You need another plugin for that and that plugin may cause other plugins to not work anymore.

Comment: ok I understand, I just wanted to deploy launchpage with wordpress to heroku... do you think thats possible?